# how can i slice a V_BSTR in c++?

Tags: c++, azure-active-directory, active-directory, type-conversion

Am working on active Directory and I need to retrieve the `userAccountControl` attribute and check for an option so I used get method as follows

```
VARIANT var;
VariantInit(&var);
hr = pUsr->Get(CComBSTR("userAccountControl"), &var);
```

and stored it in an variant  then converted it to `V_BSTR` to print the result..

```
if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
    std::cout << V_BSTR(&var) << std::endl;
}
```

the result is *0000000000010200*
Now I need to slice it  so that i get only the last 3 digits.
Is there a way to slice a bstr or to which datatype I need to convert? please help me with the conversion too

Comment: Related, fyi, if you're using ATL with this (and is certainly looks like you are based on that `CComBSTR`), you're going to want to use `ATL::CComVariant`, not `VARIANT`, for your `var`, lest you accidentally fail to remember to `VariantClear` that thing before  it expires.

Comment: am sorry am new to c++ and active directory I followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nf-iads-iads-get exactly the same and what should i do wxactly now?

Comment: std::wcout << V_BSTR(&var)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the `BSTR` to [`std::wstring`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string),
and then use [`std::wstring::substring`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) to extract the last 3 characters:

```
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    VARIANT var;
    VariantInit(&var);
    var.bstrVal = CComBSTR("0000000000010200");

    // Convert BSTR to std::wstring:
    std::wstring wstr(var.bstrVal, SysStringLen(var.bstrVal));
    assert(wstr.length() >= 3);

    // Extract last 3 characters:
    std::wstring wstrLast3chars = wstr.substr(wstr.length() - 3, 3);

    std::wcout << wstrLast3chars << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
200
```

Comment: it throws an runtime error at 
std::wstring wstr(var.bstrVal, SysStringLen(var.bstrVal));

Comment: What is the error message exactly ?

Comment: A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

Comment: I will need a [mre]. Your current post mentions the c++ side only, and my standalone c++ test is running OK in my environment.

Comment: upon further inspection it says "bstrval" is not a member of 'tagVARIANT'

Comment: It should be `bstrVal` (with capital V).

Comment: still the same runtime error

Comment: Can you try my code example as is, in a new clean project ? BTW - I am using VS2022. Which version are yo using ?

Comment: Alternatively you can try to initialize `wstr` with: `std::wstring wstr = V_BSTR(&var);`

Comment: BTW - you menioned `V_BSTR` in your code and it seems to working when `&var` is passed . `V_BSTR` is a macro that simply accesses the `bstrVal ` member via a given pointer. Therefore it is strange that you get the error you menioned above (_"bstrVal" is not a member of 'tagVARIANT'"_).